# Get element settings in Elementor preview mode

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I'm writing custom widget for Elementor. In PHP part it have some options with 'frontend_available' => true. But it outputs "data-settings" attribute only on front-end, not in Elementor's preview mode.

I use plain JS to process my settings. And this code works fine on front-end:

```js
let myElementSettings = myElement.getAttribute('data-settings');
if (myElementSettings) {
    myElementSettings = JSON.parse(myElementSettings);
}
```

But how can I get this settings in preview mode? It's okay if I'll have to add some jQuery to my script.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```js
let myElementSettings;
if (elementorFrontend.isEditMode()) {
    // preview mode
    const modelCID = myElement.getAttribute('data-model-cid');
    const elementConfig = elementorFrontend.config.elements.data[modelCID];
    if (elementConfig && elementConfig.attributes) {
        myElementSettings = elementConfig.attributes;
    }
} else {
    // front-end mode
    const elementConfig = myElement.getAttribute('data-settings');
    if (elementConfig) {
        myElementSettings = JSON.parse(elementConfig);
    }
}
```